# \charge won't work with chemfig

Tags: chemfig

While `\chemfig{...}` works when I try to make a molecule, `\charge` won't do anything.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\title{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\chemfig{\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O}-[:0]C-[:0]\charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{O}}

\chemfig{\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O}}

\chemfig{\charge{90=\.}{N}H_3}

\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O}

\end{document}
```

gives
https://www.overleaf.com/read/rrfbvdfrrrrg.

Even if I use nothing but the package chemfig, it still won't work: https://www.overleaf.com/read/cqyntshmwrmd

This is really confusing, the error message says "undefined control sequence" when `\charge` should be defined.

Comment: Which version of `chemfig` do you use? If I remember correctly, `\charge` was introduced with version 1.5 in march 2020. Probably your `chemfig` version is older?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I use Overleaf for LaTeX and can't figure out what version is already there since I didn't need to download and attach any files to use `chemfig`.

(Actually in the Overleaf settings it says that the compiler is pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: Overleaf aparently uses texlive 2019 for their compilation which in turn seems to contain `chemfig` version 1.4, which in turn does not yet know the `\charge` command.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I find a more updated version and replace it?

Comment: Oh no, I downloaded `chemfig.sty` and `chemfig.tex` from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/chemfig) and it didn't work, I'm guessing I need to download the english version, `chemfig-en.tex`